# Am i fetching records correctly in JAVA?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Sorry for the title, but I couldn't come up with anything more specific.

I am a Rails developer for the past 7 years and now I am learning Java for Android applications.

In rails, to fetch a record from the database, I use this command:

```
user = User.find(1)
```

This will return me a User object containing all the columns and information I need. To access them I can simply call methods on that object, like: `user.first_name`

In Java I am doing something like this:

```
public User getUser(String userEmail, Context context) {
    DBHelper helper = new DBHelper(context);
    db = helper.getWritableDatabase();

    String query[] = { userEmail };

    SQLiteQueryBuilder builder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    builder.setTables(helper.TABLE_USERS);

    Cursor cursor = null;

    try {
        cursor = builder.query(db, null, " email = ? ", query, null, null, null);

        User user = null;
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0 && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            user = new User();
            user.setId(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("id")));
            user.setNome(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("nome")));
            user.setToken(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("token")));
            user.setRole(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("role")));
        }

        return user;
    } finally {
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

Is this correct? Do I really need to instantiate an empty User object and fill every attribute manually by requesting them from the database (i.e. `user.setId(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("id")));`)

Is there an easier way to fetch records and work with them without needing all this?

Comment: This is far less about Java as it is about the particular library you chose to use (sqlite). Check out `jOOQ` instead if you're interested in concise, type-safe Java API to build pure SQL. If you're more interested in `ActiveRecord`-like object-relational mapping, then check out Hibernate.

Comment: What @MarkoTopolnik... or sugar ORM... etc.

Comment: Thank you for the insights. I will take a look at them.